# How to resolve specifically the error "Option clash for package xcolor. \RequirePackage" between tikzposter and ProfCollege

Tags: color, tikzposter

I know that the error "Option clash for package xcolor. \RequirePackage" has been solved in numerous situations.
However I don't know how to do it with the combination tikzposter and profcollege. My document starts with

```
\documentclass[25pt, a1paper, landscape]{tikzposter} % See Section 3

%tableau 01
\usepackage{ProfCollege}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\colorlet{mongris}{gray!15}
```

Calling \usepackage{ProfCollege} triggers the error.

One can find the lines in ProfCollege.sty:

```
\RequirePackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}%Gestion des couleurs
\RequirePackage{xstring}%Gestion de chaines de caractères
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably both `tikzposter` and `ProfCollege` loads `xcolor` but only the latter with options. This currently gives issues in LaTeX.

The standard remedy  is something like

```
\RequirePackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\documentclass[25pt, a1paper, landscape]{tikzposter}
```

Because now `xcolor` will have been loaded with `table` and `svgnames` at the time `tikzposter` loads `xcolor` as well, and in that case then loading in `tikzposter` does nothing.

As far as I know there are being worked on this option class issue. Though when that work is completed is unknown.

Comment: You're great! Many thanks.